# How to use background-clip border-box correctly

Tags: css

For some reason I don't understand `background-clip: border-box`. I can do it using an additional parent div, but would prefer not to. See:

```css
#bgbox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

#bgbox__inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #BADA55;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/tBEjfgJ.png);
  background-clip: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgbox">
  <div id="bgbox__inner"></div>
</div>
```

The background should span the borders as well. Why it does not happen?

Comment: there is no border in your code, share the code where you are trying to use it. Note that border-box is the default value of background-clip

Comment: I was looking for margin-box which is nonexistant. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of theory:
using background-clip you can control 3 ways of background image inside an element
[image]

background-clip: content-box shows bg image only in content area, ignores padding and border.
background-clip: padding-box shows bg image in padding area, ignores border. 
background-clip: border-box shows bg image in border area, if border color is transparent.

In your case, to get the result you shouldn't use background image in child element. Lets add it to parent block and make it 100% width. Because the is no way to affect margin area or any parent area from a child.

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; 
    }
    #bgbox {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      background: blue;
      background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/tBEjfgJ.png);
      background-clip: padding-box; /*not nesessery if there is no border or padding*/
    }
    
    #bgbox__inner {
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #BADA55; /* can be removed */
      padding: 0 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bgbox">
      <div id="bgbox__inner">1</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `background-clip: padding-box;` is useless here, remove it and you will have the same output

Comment: I'm just asking, which result do you need to reach. May be you don't need background-clip an all.

Comment: I am not the asker (if you want clarification, consider the comment section instead)

Comment: It's just a MVP, I have to have it for whole page width unfortunately

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but still don't understand the goal that we should reach. Could you illustrate it via image or something?

Comment: Body as parent, variable width, inner container with auto margin fixed width, but container background should span as far as body tag.

Comment: Just edited an answer. I hope, there is an answer. It is impossible to affect the parent padding using background-clip of a child.

Comment: After edit it makes sense I wasn't right in my way of thinking, thank you